# Running Orleans Silo in Azure function app isolated process

Tags: azure-functions, orleans

I'm trying to run Orleans silo(s) in Azure function app isolated process.
First time it seems running fine, but a couple hours later the function fails with connection errors
[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r84TW.png)

I found in OrleansMembershipTable that many Silos are registered there with private IP address (192.168.7.32, 192.168.4.108, 192.168.7.254...) Apparently the function app is constantly instantiated and disposed
[OrleansMembershipTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc3ek.png)

Okay it can happen but my question is, shouldn't it be handled automatically by Orleans, if a silo is already dead, instead of failing request by connection error to the dead silo?

Or is it not possible to run Silos in isolated function app? I could find some example using separated Azure web job (silo) + Function app (Orleans client), which makes sense but I'd prefer having a single app, simpler architecture

Comment: I think I've found the problem - I have separated cluster id for my local environment and Azure environment, and now all works fine. They find the dead silo immediately, and no connection error occurs. Azure function app still starts up periodically without my control, but it doesn't fail now

Comment: please add your steps as an answer and [Accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who might spend time like me, the conclusion is Function App can't host Silos - because Function App instances can't talk to each other. There might be some way to have a virtual network in dedicated plan, but not in consumption/premium plan. Our Microsoft contacts were quite adamant NOT TO USE Function app for hosting Orleans

Instead now we are using Azure Container App

Answer (score 1):

It was a kind of user error : I was using the same deployment id for my local development and Azure deployment, and they each other could not confirm dead or alive, messing up the service.

I have separated the cluster id for my local development and Azure deployment, as in the screenshot :

[Membership Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ed5N.png)

Then everything works fine. Although still Azure function app restarts itself occasionally, they detect the dead silo immediately and clean up the states.